# GCC ARM cross compiler won't compile simple Hello world

Tags: android, c, gcc, arm

I recently installed ARM C compiler for Android using `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`.
It installed successfully, so I wrote a simple Hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("Hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

I saved it as hello.c and then tried to compile it using: `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello`
But it says:

```
usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Install one of `libc6-dev-armel-armhf-cross`, `libc6-dev-armel-cross`, `libc6-dev-armhf-armel-cross`, or `libc6-dev-armhf-cross` or whatever the package is for your Debian/Ubuntu; these are the packages that work with this compiler, afaik.  You need to tell us your hosting PC architecture and Linux distribution.  Err, you need `libbonic` or something.  Are you sure you have the right compiler?  Even if you compile/link, I don't think your code will work on Android.

Comment: @artlessnoise Thank you, it worked. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: I think you want `gcc-arm-linux-androideabi` and not `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`, if you have that package.  I will make an answer if you supply the Debian/Ubuntu version you are using and verify the code actually runs on Android.  You may have a compile/link, but I think it is built for the wrong system; a plain ARM/Linux.